# R gives wrong DF for one variable in ANOVA table

Tags: r

I've been trying to run an ANOVA on a pilot study I conducted looking at the impact of toxin production on growth rates across 3 time points using 8 different strains (isolates). Isolates are always either tox or nontox. For some reason, however, r keeps giving me 6 degrees of freedom for my isolates instead of 7. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Sorry the following tables aren't really tables i'm new to this and am not sure how to get it to align properly.

```
> data

   isolate   size time tox
1     1644 1.4625    1   1
2     1644 2.6300    2   1
3     1644 3.9700    3   1
4     1694 1.5625    1   1
5     1694 2.6625    2   1
6     1694 3.9125    3   1
7     1654 1.3875    1   0
8     1654 2.4125    2   0
9     1654 3.6875    3   0
10    2195 1.7275    1   1
11    2195 2.9875    2   1
12    2195 3.9625    3   1
13    1698 1.2875    1   0
14    1698 2.4375    2   0
15    1698 4.0500    3   0
16    2192 1.4250    1   0
17    2192 2.2525    2   0
18    2192 4.0000    3   0
19    2205 1.5375    1   1
20    2205 2.8750    2   1
21    2205 3.9125    3   1
22    2208 1.0375    1   0
23    2208 1.8375    2   0
24    2208 2.7750    3   0

data <- aov(size ~ factor(tox) + factor(time) + factor(isolate))
summary(data)

                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
 factor(tox)      1  0.886   0.886  24.890 0.000199 ***
 factor(time)     2 22.237  11.119 312.183 2.44e-12 ***
 factor(isolate)  6  1.086   0.181   5.083 0.005782 ** 
 Residuals       14  0.499   0.036                     

 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> factor(isolate)

[1] 1644 1644 1644 1694 1694 1694 1654 1654 1654 2195 2195 2195 1698
1698 1698  2192 2192 2192

[19] 2205 2205 2205 2208 2208 2208

Levels: 1644 1654 1694 1698 2192 2195 2205 2208
```

Comment: This sounds like a statistical question to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what happens here is that the model sees indeed 7 groups for the variable "isolate", but it needs only 6 of those, when the other variables are present. This is possible when the variability in one of those groups is a linear combination of some other variables.

If you do :

```
> data <- lm(size ~ factor(tox) + factor(time) + factor(isolate))
> summary(data)

Call:
lm(formula = size ~ factor(tox) + factor(time) + factor(isolate))

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.315000 -0.083542 -0.006458  0.047813  0.298750 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.74125    0.12208   6.072 2.88e-05 ***
factor(tox)1         0.80000    0.15442   5.181 0.000139 ***
factor(time)2        1.08250    0.09456  11.448 1.71e-08 ***
factor(time)3        2.35375    0.09456  24.891 5.44e-13 ***
factor(isolate)1654  0.61000    0.15442   3.950 0.001451 ** 
factor(isolate)1694  0.02333    0.15442   0.151 0.882048    
factor(isolate)1698  0.70667    0.15442   4.576 0.000431 ***
factor(isolate)2192  0.67333    0.15442   4.360 0.000653 ***
factor(isolate)2195  0.20667    0.15442   1.338 0.202110    
factor(isolate)2205  0.09000    0.15442   0.583 0.569274    
factor(isolate)2208       NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1891 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9797,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9667 
F-statistic: 75.08 on 9 and 14 DF,  p-value: 2.707e-10
```

You'll notice the NA value for isolate group = 2208.
That means that this group is not needed by the model (when the other 2 variables are present).